# How to assign coordinates as props to Marker component for Google Maps, in React?

Tags: reactjs, json, react-google-maps-api

I am using google-maps-API for my React project. I was able to create a marker on my google maps, with constant coordinates. But what I would like to do is, read the coordinates from a JSON file and pass them as props to my position attribute, in my marker component. I have imported the JSON file as Data and used map function to assign coordinates to my marker.

> import { GoogleMap, Marker, useLoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api";
> import { useMemo } from "react";
> import Data from './xxx.json';
>
> var new1;
> export default function Maps(){
> const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
> googleMapsApiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
> });
> const center = useMemo(() => ({ lat: 40.117862 , lng: -83.178291 }), []);
>
> return (
>
> {!isLoaded ? (
>
> ## Loading...
>
> ) : (
>
> {
> Data.map((item,id)=>(
> //console.log("lat: "+item['coordinatesX'],"lon: "+item['coordinatesY'])
>
> new1= useMemo(() => (( lat: {item['coordinatesX']},lng:{item['coordinatesY']}))
>
> ```
>           <Marker position={{ lat: {item[coordinatesX], lng: {item[coordinatesY]} }} ></Marker>
>
>         ))
>
>
>        </GoogleMap>
>       )}
>     </div>
>   )
> ```
>
> }
> This is error I have-

> SyntaxError: X:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (32:44)
>
> 30 |
> 31 |
> 32 |               <Marker position={{ lat: {item[coordinatesX], lng: {item[coordinatesY]} }} >
> |                                             ^
> 33 |
> 34 |             ))
> 35 |           }

> Line 32:44:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (32:44)
>
> webpack compiled with 2 errors and 1 warning

I just need to know the appropriate syntax to render my markers dynamically with map function.